# Problem when consuming endpoint that returns content in parts with Flutter

Tags: python, flutter, rest, video-streaming, fastapi

I have this Fastapi endpoint

```
@router.get("/stream/{id}")
async def stream_numbers(id: str, range: str = Header(None)):
    start, end = range.replace("bytes=", "").split("-")
    start: int = int(start)
    end: int = int(start + PORTION_SIZE)
    
    data, size_video = await VideoService.stream_one(id = id, start = start, end = end)
    
    if not data or not size_video:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Video Not found.")
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Range': f'bytes {str(start)}-{str(end)}/{size_video}',
        'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'
    }
    return Response(content=data, status_code=206, headers=headers, media_type="video/mp4")
```

This endpoint returns 1 mb of a video, the problem is that I haven't found a way to play the portion of the video received in Flutter.

How could I consume that endpoint without dying in the attempt?

Thank you so much.

I was trying with video_player, using its file constructor, first it transformed the api response into a UINT8List and this in turn into a File, but that didn't work.